# I need to include all my function in eventloop?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

If i have a event loop and async function:

```
# asyncio_coroutine_forever.py


import asyncio

async def hello_world():
    print('Hello World')
    await good_evening()


async def good_evening():
    print('Good Evening')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(hello_world())
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    print('closing event loop')
    loop.close()
```

The function hellp_world, is called by eventloop. The second function good_evening, is in the same eventloop or not?

Do I have to include the second function in the loop or just the first one?
If i use the example, the second use loop and switch the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, `run_until_complete` will execute your `hello_world` future until it returns or fails (it will also block your thread in the process).
2. You don't have to include the second function unless you want to schedule it by itself.

`run_until_complete` will run a future until it's finished but, it will also cause the event loop to run so if you schedule a future it will run before the function passed to `run_util_complete`.